# How to I get R to run svyglm on my imputed data?

Tags: r, linear-regression, survey, r-mice

(First time poster and very new to R so please be patient with me if my explanations aren't very clear)

I have a dataset with one outcome measure collected at two timepoints (21 months and 7 years of age). Missing data on the outcome measure at the second timepoint was imputed with mice. I now want to run some linear regression models using svyglm for both timepoints but I think the imputed data isn't being used as the df at the second timepoint is way lower than the first timepoint. The total sample size at both timepoints should be 2591.

I'm also adjusting for clustering within families as I'm using twin data using the FamID variable in my dataset.

My code is:

```
#run imputation itself
df1_imp<- mice(imp, max=50, m=20, pred=predM, seed=5)



#adjust for family clustering

imp_list <- lapply( 1:20 , function( n ) complete(df1_imp , action = n ) )
df1_imp_data <- svydesign(ids=~famID, probs=~1, data=imputationList(imp_list), nest=TRUE)



## 21 months SES and UPF
#Model 1

SES21m <- with(df1_imp_data, svyglm(UPF_21m ~ SES_compositeWeighted, design = df1_imp_data))
summary(pool(SES21m))

## 7 years SES and UPF
#Model 1

SES7y <- with(df1_imp_data, svyglm(UPF_7y ~ SES_compositeWeighted, design = df1_imp_data))
summary(pool(SES7y))
```

My output for the 21 month model is:

```
                   term estimate std.error statistic     df     p.value
1           (Intercept)  58.5069   1.52126   38.4595 1284.0 6.3124e-216
2 SES_compositeWeighted  -2.5414   0.31247   -8.1333 1282.7  9.7675e-16
```

My output for the 7 year model is:

```
                   term estimate std.error statistic      df    p.value
1           (Intercept)  67.4022   1.53660   43.8644  62.349 1.4021e-48
2 SES_compositeWeighted  -1.3201   0.29022   -4.5486 100.121 1.5178e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

The `df` reported there isn't based just on the sample size (which is why it isn't a whole number). It is lower, because part of the variance estimate comes from between-imputation comparisons, which have only as many df as there are imputations.

The easiest way to see if you are using all the data is to look at the individual `svyglm` objects in `SES7y` before you pool them.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me, yes I didn't even realise that in the data tab in the Environment window it says my model SES7y is a list of 20, which must mean its using the imputed data as there are 20 imputations!